# Disable Ubercart download limits accumulation

Tags: ubercart, files

By default the [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) module, accumulate the download limit of a file if this one is purchased twice. How can i disable this ?. I just want to notify the user that he already have privilege to download the file and prevent him from downloading it again.

Answer (score 0):

Set the download limit as **Unlimited**, then at the next time user click on add to cart button, then check this product is he already checkout or not (for this you can use order table). If it is already purchased by that user, then you can redirect him separate page or you can display a message about the same.

Comment: I actually need the download limit for each file to be limited at 20 times, but i think that what you suggest work's in both cases (unlimited or not), i'll try that and get back to you. thank's